# What are the various column types you can have in StorIO?

Tags: android, sqlite, storio

I know for sure that String & Long is ok because they are part of the sample app. What else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our Annotation Processor will fail the compilation if your field type is not supported, so you can try to annotate any field and compile the project without worries about app crash at the runtime.

I've created an issue [Add info about supported field types (Annotation Processor)](https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio/issues/497) and I'll add this info to the readme asap!

**UPD:**

Here is a class with all types of fields supported by StorIO SQLite Annotation Processor [AllSupportedTypes.java](https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio/blob/master/storio-sample-app/src/main/java/com/pushtorefresh/storio/sample/db/entities/AllSupportedTypes.java)

Comment: @Sree I've added class with all types of fields supported by StorIO Annotation Processor, please take a look :)